# drupal 7 new module install link don't show

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

[image]

When i go to modules tab i can't find "new module install" link

Please tell me how to view this new module install link in drupal-7

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You're also missing the "Update" tab which leads me to believe you don't have the "Update Manager" module enabled. It's in the list under "Core", just enable that and the "Install new module" link will appear.

Answer (score 2):

Try empty your cache at `/configuration/development/performance`.
Also, make sure that you have placed your new module inside the `/sites/all/modules` folder.

Comment: why don't show new module link in modules Tab? This link remove in new version of drupal-7

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? What do you mean by "why don't show new module link in modules Tab"? When you add a new module to the `/sites/all/modules` directory a section for this module should appear under `/admin/modules`.

Answer (score 0):

try to install "Update manager Module" first.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please enable update manager core module
2. Please provide the enough permission for "sites/all/modules"